# Select everything between quotes containing a partial keyword

Tags: c#, regex

I want to retrieve the full string between quote marks which matches on a partial keyword.

Suppose I have a keyword (i.e. `example-a`) which is part of a directory structure (i.e `"/tutorial/example/example-a/"`).

I've tried `"(.*?)"` which returns all string instances between quotes from an example input. I don't like the idea of having to iterate the `MatchCollection` to find if it contains the target keyword as my current match is roughly 1700+. I'm able to cast the `MatchCollection` to a list for me to then interrogate if the capture group contains the keyword and this is working at the moment.

So my expectation would be that for an input `"/tutorial/example/example-a/"`, I can pass any string for my keyword, in this case `example-a` and return the value inside the quote mark `/tutorial/example/example-a/`.

Is there a way to achieve this within a single regex? Or perhaps a better approach to achieve my desired results?

Comment: string.Split(text, Quotes)?,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of Regex "lookeahead", e.g. in the pattern

```
"([^"]*(?=example-a)[^"]*)"
```

we match a double quote mark followed by anything but the closing double quote, but the part `(?=example-a)` (the positive lookeahad assertion) tells to only continue matching if `example-a` is found before `"` matches the closing quote mark. This is called a zero length assertion because it doesn't add anything to the matched characters but can control whether or not to match. `(` and `)` next to the quote marks captures the part inside them.

https://regex101.com/r/bUd8lf/2/